# Casting an unsigned long long int to signed long long int Is it possible?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

Data from sensors comes in 2 formats **SaHpiUint64T** and **SaHpiInt64T**  and application is designed to handle only **SaHpiUint64T**  data.

Casting if possible what could be the side effects ??

```
/* unsigned 64-bit data, 8-byte alignment  */
typedef unsigned long long int  SaHpiUint64T __attribute__((__aligned__(8)));

/* signed 64-bit data, 8-byte alignment    */
typedef signed long long int SaHpiInt64T __attribute__((__aligned__(8)));
```

Comment: Instead of paying back your mortgage, you end up buying a second house?

Comment: To clarify - are you casting from signed to unsigned, or unsigned to signed?

Comment: How wide is your processor word and what data are you expecting from the sensor? Can the sensor return a negative value?

Comment: How are you going to distinguish a negative integer from a very large positive integer if you cast a signed integer to unsigned integer?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes at this point of time yes buying a second house seems helpful.

Comment: @Chowlett I wish to cast from signed to unsigned

Comment: @nonsensickle Yes the sensor may return a negative value for temperature which is very rare on a linux system

Comment: @leeduhem totally agree with you but I don't get negative values from the sensors.

Comment: I would love to know what kind of a sensor has 63 bits of accuracy...

Comment: "the sensor may return a negative value for temperature which is very rare on a linux system" Well there you go. The sensor can return a negative value so you must handle it, end of story. What if the computer is moved into a cool server room? What if the sensor goes haywire? Once you have handled the negative numbers and after that made sure that the number you are about to process is not negative, then cast it to an unsigned.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Which one are you using? (It could matter; C++ has several forms of cast operators that C lacks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You don't even need a cast. Simply assign your `long long int` to an `unsigned long long int` variable.

However, a `long long int` can of course contain negative values. There is no problem if your `long long int` sensor readings are never negative. If they can be negative, those negative values will become large positive numbers on the conversion to an `unsigned long long int`. How you deal with this, and if you deal with it, that's up to you.

If you know that a sensor can yield negative values, it makes a lot more sense to add an offset so that the the offset value is always non-negative. Two choices are the minimum possible sensor reading and the minimum `unsigned long long int`. With this offset approach there is no longer a discontinuity at the largest possible signed value.

Comment: In existing code I am getting long positive value so do you think it is due to this improper casting ??? and do these long positive values never change even if it represent a parameter which is continuously changing like power on time

Comment: You don't *have* to cast, but you will end up with a compiler warning (and rightfully so). Casting explicitly (`static_cast<unsigned long long>( ... )`) not only makes the warning go away, it also tells the poor sod of a maintenance coder that's coming after you that you **have** considered the implications. (You did, didn't you?)

Comment: @DevSolar -- Re *but you will end up with a compiler warning.* Not with gcc or clang, at least not with a fairly standard set of warnings enabled (e.g., `-Wall -Wextra`). You need to explicitly specify the compiler option `-Wconversion` with gcc/clang to get a warning on implicitly converting a signed integer to the same size unsigned integer. (And even that doesn't do it for C++. You need to specify `-Wsign-conversion` as a compiler option to get this warning.)

Comment: @DevSolar -- Nonetheless, a cast is a very good idea here because it signals intent.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Actually my "standard" set of warnings looks more like "everything and the kitchen sink" and spans three lines in my Makefiles, so I didn't even consider the inappropriateness of `-Wall -Wextra`. ;-) You're right, of course - `-Wall -Wextra` doesn't cut it.

Comment: Can u help me understand why I am getting long positive values which are not changing even after casting and before casting :(

Comment: @yanivx - There's no problem converting a signed int to an unsigned int in the case of non-negative values. They convert exactly. If you are seeing those large positive values in the signed integers themselves, it's your sensors. The problem lies with sensors whose output is a signed integer that can produce negative readings. Those negative values become very large positive numbers on conversion to an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can cast them, but you might be interpreting you data completely wrong :D

The last bit (highest value) of your integer variable is the sign of the variable in case of a signed int.

Now if you're sensing in signed values, and you sense a negative variable, and you cast it to an unsigned variable, you'll end up with a very large number (2^63 + abs(original variable)) in this case.

And if you are sensing in unsigned form, and you sense a value larger than 2^63, and you cast it to a signed int, you will end up with a value equal to (original value - 2^63) which is a negative value.

Therefore if you're sure about the range of your sensory data, then you can safely cast between the two, otherwise not.